# How to highlight a word in another element using Regex and anchor tags

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace

I want to be able to click on the anchor tag and have it highlight the corresponding word in the div below it.  It seems like every example I've seen to do this requires an input, but I'd like to be able to do it with a button or anchor tag.  Here is my fiddle that's not working yet.  Is there something I'm missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/NVeMD/6/

```
$('#search').click(function () {
    var test = new RegExp(
        $('#search').text().replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 
        'gi');
    $('#sample').children().addBack().not('.highlight').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).replaceWith(function(){
        return this.str.replace(test, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
    });
});

$('#revert').click(function(){
    $(".highlight").contents().unwrap();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I couldn't understand your code very well. but I've coded something that works for what you need, i.e:

---

When `#search` is clicked we retrieve its `text()` and replace `#sample` with `<span class="highlight">text of #search</span>`.
When `#revert` is clicked we replace `#sample` `html()` with `#sample` `text()` only.

---

```js
$('#search').click(function () {
    var re = new RegExp("\\b" + $("#search").text() + "\\b","ig");
    $("#sample").html($("#sample").text().replace(re, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>'))
});

$('#revert').click(function(){
    $("#sample").html($("#sample").text());
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="search">Yoda</a>
<button id="revert">Revert!</button>
<p id="sample">Highlight the word Yoda Yodada</p>
```

---

**Note:**

1. The regex has **word boundaries** (`\b`) and will match `Yoda` but
   **not** `Yodada`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!  Looks like I was trying to boil the ocean on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code and the already replied answers aren't incorrect, but can potentially have a negative impact. Using `.html()` with jQuery or `innerHTML` with VanillaJS will destroy all the events on the element and also trigger generation of the DOM again and again. So, please stop doing it this way, otherwise you will run into further pitalls. **Use a already existing component that was build for this**!

**Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)**, a highlighter for keywords/search terms or custom regular expressions. It is also available as jQuery plugin.
The following example shows you how to highlight a text entered inside a input dynamically inside a context with [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) (see demo below).

```js
var markInstance = new Mark(document.querySelector(".context"));
function highlight(){
    var searchTerm = document.querySelector("input").value;
    markInstance.unmark().mark(searchTerm);
}
```

```css
mark{
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/julmot/mark.js/6.1.0/dist/mark.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum..." oninput="highlight()">
<p class="context">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I was able to get working.  It's not exactly the same as what you tried, particularly with regard to finding the text to replace.

```
$('#search').click(function () {
    var newtext = $('#search').text().replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    var test = new RegExp(newtext, 'gi');
    $('#sample').html($('#sample').text().replace(test, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>'));
});
```

This will highlight the word selected.  The code with the filter didn't make sense to me as to what you were trying to achieve, so I simplified to make the highlight work.